# Set Charts.newCategoryFilter() to be pre-filtered

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script which takes all of the data from a Google Sheet and displays it in a table. I've included several category filters in this so that the user is able to select which data they want to see.

However, I am now looking to take this even further my pre-filtering one of my columns so that it only displays results that are "Closed". I would then create a copy of this file and change it to only showing "Open" results.

Is this possible to do? See a simplified version of my script below. For reference, it's the outcomeFilter that I'm wanting to pre-filter.

```
 function doGet() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetkey');
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
   var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();
 for( var j in data[0] )
   if (data[23][j] != 'Closed') {
   dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, data[0][j]);
 for( var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i )
   dataTable.addRow(data[i].map(String));


   var stageFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(21).build();
   var outcomeFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(23).build();
   //var testFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(24).build();
   //var testFilter2 = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(25).build();

   var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
   .setDimensions(1900, 2000)
   .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11/*,12*/,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]))
   .build()
   ;

   var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(dataTable)
   .bind([stageFilter, outcomeFilter/*, testFilter, testFilter2*/],[tableChart])
   .build();

   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   var filterPanel1 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
   var filterPanel2 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
   var filterPanel3 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
   var filterPanel4 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
   //var testPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
   var chartPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();

   filterPanel4.add(stageFilter).add(outcomeFilter).setSpacing(10);
   //testPanel.add(testFilter).add(testFilter2).setSpacing(10);
   chartPanel.add(tableChart).setSpacing(10);

   dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel1).add(filterPanel2).add(filterPanel3).add(filterPanel4)/*.add(testPanel)*/.add(chartPanel));
   app.add(dashboard);
   return app;
 }
 }
```

This is the absolute bare bones of my script to try and reduce down the size of the question.

I am also aware I've probably not gone about my code in the best way, but I'm still getting used to working with Apps Script.

**EDIT -** I've managed to make myself a workaround, where I create two sheets, one which is formulated to only show "Closed" entries and the other is formulated to show only "Open" entries. I have then created a quick apps script which sorts the shown records Z-A.

It works and is a good workaround, but it's annoying that I've got to update two files every time I want to make a mistake. **- EDIT**

Answer (score 0):

Before you get the data, you could sort the data by the column that you want to exclude values from.

[Google Documentation Sort a Sheet Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

You already have a `For` loop iterating through every row of your data, so you could add a condition to stop the loop when it gets to a value that you don't want.

```
for (var j in data[0] ) {
  if (data[columnYouWantToCheck][j] === valueToExclude) {
    break; //End this iteration here if row is unwanted.  If you sorted the data.
  };
};
```

The `break;` will kill the loop, so only use that if you presorted the data.  You could also set up the condition like this:

```
for (var j in data[0] ) {
  if (data[columnYouWantToCheck][j] != valueToExclude) {
    //All your code here for data in include.
  };
};
```

Comment: I tried this in various formats today, mainly using the second option. My code here ended up as:
     for (var j in data[0] ) {
       if (data[23][j] != "Closed") { // I also tried creating a new var and defining that as "Closed".

// Rest of code

};
};

This doesn't do anything with the filter, however.

Comment: We need to know exactly what line of code is not working.  View the **Execution Transcript**; use `Logger.log('Some Variable Name: ' + varName);` and then view the log.  Use the debugger to step through the code.  You can update your question with any new code you tried.  Tell us what is getting returned for a specific variable.  Post error messages that you are getting.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the changes on lines 8 and 44. I wasn't actually getting an error when I ran it like this. Its just that it was showing both 'Open' and 'Closed' entries

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter that will by default have the value "Closed" and be impossible to change to another value using

```
var testFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setAllowNone(false).setValues(['Closed']);
```

Comment: I've just tried adding that in, along with all the filterPanels etc to go with it but I get the following error when I go to run it: "Cannot convert Array to Control[]."

Comment: i just doublechecked and it does work for me when i just drop it into some other old script. can you create a public mock data spreadsheet?